# Degrees of irreducible representations are the same for all splitting fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory

Suppose $G$ is a finite group. Given any splitting field $K$ for $G$ such that the characteristic of $K$ does not divide the order of $G$, it is possible to construct a bijection between the irreducible representations of $G$ over $K$ and the irreducible representations of $G$ over the field of complex numbers, such that the bijection preserves the degree of a representation.

This claim explains why we often research the complex representation of finite groups. I want to know, what is the bijection ?